# How can I give write permission to "/mnt/pidrive1" path?

Tags: raspbian, permissions, sudo

I have connected an USB drive with my Raspberry Pi following [this](https://blog.alexellis.io/attach-usb-storage/) tutorial. Everything worked fine but I'm not able to rename, delete or move/copy any files to a folder using SFTP. I'm only able to put files in it using SSH with `sudo` before every command.

Comment: I inserted and mounted a USB drive into my Pi. Via SSH from my laptop to the Pi I am able to rename, delete, move folders on the USB drive with help of sudo. Where does SFTP come in?

Comment: My first suggestion: Ask your question of Alex Ellis - the author of the tutorial you followed. If he's publishing tutorials, presumably he's knowledgeable re permissions issues, and certainly more familiar with the details of his own approach. It doesn't look right to me, but I could have overlooked something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this problem with this command:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /mnt/pidrive1
```